# what are the limitation on current Mathematica's ability to solving a Sturm-Liouville ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

**Update**

fyi. CASE:3855831 (thanks to bbgodfrey reporting it)

---

Mathematica 11 is supposed to be able to solve `basic` S-L ODE according to [this page](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/partial-differential-equations/solve-a-basic-sturm-liouville-problem.html?product=language)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it works for some, but found an example where it does not work for.

Is there a way to quantify the current limitation of what type of S-L  ODE's `DSolve` can handle, other than by trying and finding out, or to find out why it could not solve this specific example below?

For example 11.0.1 can solve these `basic` SL

```
  ode=y''[x]+ lam x^2 y[x]==0;
  ode=y''[x]+ lam  y[x]==0;
  ode=y''[x]+ lam  Sin[x]^2 y[x]==0;
```

But for some reason, it can't solve this

```
  ode=y''[x]+ lam (1+Sin[x])^2 y[x]==0;
```

All examples were tried using command `DSolve[ode,y[x],x]`. I did not give the two boundary conditions here to keep it simple.

Windows 7, Mathematica 11.0.1, 64 bit

Reference

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sturm-LiouvilleEquation.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

**Update:**

To answer comment:

This has exact analytical solution (verified) given by Maple 2016 using [HeunC](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC) special function. (I do not know yet how to convert the solution to other special functions like hypergeom so I can translate the solution to Mathematica, since Mathematica does not have Heun special functions build-in).

```
restart;
ode:=diff(y(x),x$2)+lam*(1+sin(x))^2*y(x)=0;
dsolve(ode,y(x));
```

And the answer is

```
y(x) = _C1*exp(lam^(1/2)*sin(x))*
    HeunC(4*lam^(1/2), -1/2, -1/2, -4*lam, 3/8 (1/2)*
    sin(x)+1/2)+_C2*exp(lam^(1/2)*sin(x))*
    HeunC(4*lam^(1/2), 1/2, -1/2, -4*lam, 3/8, (1/2)*sin(x)+1/2)*
    (2*sin(x)+2)^(1/2)
```

screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Mathematica can't solve `DSolve[2 lam Sin[x] y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[x], x]`, do you think it is related?

Comment: @happyfish  This might be related yes. But in S-L, the term  multiplying the `y(x)` is called the weight (not the lambda), and weight should be positive quantity for S-L strict definition. [Liouville_theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory). So without knowing the range of `x`, the weight `Sin[x]` can be negative. But M should still be able to solve it I would think.

Comment: Despite `Cos[x]` being in the same situation, `DSolve[2 lam Cos[x] y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[x], x]` can be solved. A more interesting observation: while `DSolve[2 lam Cos[x - Pi/2] y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[x], x]` can't be solved(it returns the same equation in my previous comment), `DSolve[2 lam Cos[x - Pi/2.] y[x] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[x], x]` can be solved.

Comment: @happyfish  Although `DSolve` cannot be expected to solve all S-L problems, it certainly should be able to solve the well known Mattieu equation, especially when it can solve essentially equivalent ODEs.  This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Nasser  `y''[x]+ lam (1+Sin[x])^2 y[x]==0` looks like a form of the Whittaker-Hill equation.  Does it have a closed-form solution?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes. It has closed form solution, but Maple gives the solution in terms of HuenC function. Will update my question now with this information in case it help. Thanks

Comment: I have reported these issues to Wolfram, Inc as CASE:3855831.